# Help Proving $F = E(a)$, abstract algebra, extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be an extension field of degree $2$ over a field $E$.
Prove that if $E$ is not of characteristic $2$ then $F = E(\alpha)$
with $Irr(\alpha, E) = x^2 − b$

Comment: Learn MathJax and share your thoughts/work on the problem rather than simply quoting the question.

Answer (score 0):

we have $F$ extension over $E$ of degree 2 and $\alpha\in F$ then 
$$E(\alpha)={ [{c+d\alpha ; c,d\in E}]=F }$$
we have $E\subset F$ and $\alpha \in F$ then $E(\alpha) \subseteq F$.

we have $c,d\in E$ then $c,d\alpha \in E(\alpha)$ then $c+d\alpha \in E(\alpha)$ $\Rightarrow F\subseteq E(\alpha)  $.

and $Irr(\alpha,E)=x^2-b; \alpha^2=b$
if $x^2-b $ is reducible then $x^2-b=(a_1x+a_2)(a_3x+a_4);$$a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\in E$

then  $x^2-b=a_1a_3x^2+(a_2a_3+a_1a_4)x+a_2a_4 \Leftrightarrow a_1a_3=1 , a_2a_3+a_1a_4=0 , a_1a_4=-b$ then $a_2^2=b \Rightarrow a_2^2=\alpha^2 $ then $\alpha \in E$ contradiction.